# On a set of points uniformly distributed in a circle, on average, what would be better? Graham's scan or Jarvis's march

Tags: average-case, convex-hull

I got this question in an exam and my approach was to use probability.

Jarvis's march is better than Graham's scan if h < log(n)

So I calculated the probability of a point being on the circle boundary and showed that since probability of being on the circle < log(probability of being inside the circle), Jarvis's march is better. Was this approach correct? And if not, what would the correct approach be?

Comment: The boundary has zero area, the interior of a non-degenerate circle more than that.